# g++ compiler error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘>’ token only on Mac

Tags: c++, stl, compiler-errors

I've got a program that won't compile on a Mac (gcc 4.2.1, Apple Inc. build 5658) but seems to have no trouble on a Linux (gcc 4.7.2). I get the above error when I try to write a class with member functions that take STL vectors containing STL pair objects:

test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_

#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

class testclass
{
public:
  void printcontent(const std::vector<std::string> & = std::vector<std::string>());
  void printother(const std::vector<std::pair<float,float> >& = std::vector<std::pair<float,float> >());
};
#endif
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



void testclass::printcontent(const vector<string> &v)
{

  if (v.empty())
    cout << "vector was empty!" << endl;
  else
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
      cout << v.at(i) << endl;
}

void testclass::printother(const vector<pair<float,float> >& v)
{
  if (v.empty())
    cout << "vector was empty!" << endl;

  else
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
      cout << v.at(i).first << ' ' << v.at(i).second << endl;
}

int main()
{

  testclass tc;
  vector<string> v1;
  v1.push_back("a");
  v1.push_back("b");
  v1.push_back("c");

  tc.printcontent(v1);
  tc.printcontent();

  vector<pair<float,float> > v2;
  v2.push_back(pair<float,float>(1,2));
  v2.push_back(pair<float,float>(3,4));
  v2.push_back(pair<float,float>(5,6));

  tc.printother(v2);
  tc.printother();
}
```

If the same function prototypes are not inside a class definition, everything compiles and runs fine.

Am I making a stupid C++ error that my Linux compiler tolerates, or is this a Mac compiler problem?

The full error message:

```
$ g++ -o test test.cpp
In file included from test.cpp:1:
test.h:12: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘>’ token
test.h:12: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_pair.h:68: error: provided for ‘template<class _T1, class _T2> struct std::pair’
test.h:12: error: template argument 1 is invalid
test.h:12: error: template argument 2 is invalid
test.h:12: error: default argument missing for parameter 2 of ‘void testclass::printother(const std::vector<std::pair<float, float>, std::allocator<std::pair<float, float> > >&, float)’
test.cpp:18: error: prototype for ‘void testclass::printother(const std::vector<std::pair<float, float>, std::allocator<std::pair<float, float> > >&)’ does not match any in class ‘testclass’
test.h:12: error: candidate is: void testclass::printother(const std::vector<std::pair<float, float>, std::allocator<std::pair<float, float> > >&, float)
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:46: error: call of overloaded ‘printother(std::vector<std::pair<float, float>, std::allocator<std::pair<float, float> > >&)’ is ambiguous
test.h:12: note: candidates are: void testclass::printother(const std::vector<std::pair<float, float>, std::allocator<std::pair<float, float> > >&, float)    
test.cpp:18: note:                 void testclass::printother(const std::vector<std::pair<float, float>, std::allocator<std::pair<float, float> > >&)
```

An update... I've tested a similar example with a vector of vectors, and don't get the same error:

test2.h:

```
#ifndef TEST2_H_
#define TEST2_H_

#include <vector>

class testclass
{
public:
  void printother(const std::vector<std::vector<float> > & = std::vector<std::vector<float> >());

};
#endif
```

test2.cpp:

```
#include "test2.h"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void testclass::printother(const vector<vector<float> >& v)
{
  if (v.empty())
    cout << "vector was empty!" << endl;

  else
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
      for (unsigned j = 0; j < v.at(i).size(); j++)
        if (j < v.at(i).size() - 1)
          cout << v.at(i).at(j) << ' ';
        else
          cout << v.at(i).at(j) << endl;   
}

int main()
{
  testclass tc;

  vector<vector<float> > v2;
  v2.push_back(vector<float>());
  v2.back().push_back(0);
  v2.back().push_back(1);
  v2.back().push_back(2);

  v2.push_back(vector<float>());
  v2.back().push_back(3);
  v2.back().push_back(4);
  v2.back().push_back(5);

  tc.printother(v2);

}
```

Comment: What is the line number? Can you post the full error?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't change anything? I'd expect the error to occur when using `>>` as opposed to `> >` for the ending angle brackets.

Comment: btw, you should get warnings as you add integer types to floats

Comment: Confirmed that Xcode's g++ (4.2) and Clang++ both fail to compiler. Using a MacPorts version of g++ (4.7) compiles the code just fine.

Comment: The first error clang++ spits out:
    /test.h:12:98: error: expected ')'
      ...>& = std::vector<std::pair<float,float> >());

Comment: Here's a reduced test case: https://gist.github.com/sharth/1989d513dfecbff15f0d

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a compiler bug in Apple's version.  I think you can work it around by naming your parameter and adding parents around your default value:

```
void printother(const std::vector<std::pair<float,float> >& ref = (std::vector<std::pair<float,float> >()));
                                                            ^     ^                                      ^
```

Comment: You only need the parentheses. Naming isn't necessary.

Comment: Wow. This totally worked. I was 99% sure I was just doing something dumb.
This doesn't seem to affect all empty vector default arguments, just the pair (is this something about the double '>'? If I'd had a std::vector<std::vector> > would that have had the same problem?)

Comment: Well it's a parsing bug.  C++ is notoriously hard to parse.  I am not surprised that the more template arguments, the most likely you can get parsing bugs.  Now, it's hard to know what will trigger it without looking at the gcc code.  The best way is to try to compile the code and see :)

Comment: Indeed. It's not a problem with a 2D std::vector... see above.